# How can I increment a specific year using datetime datatype in mysql?

Tags: mysql, datetime

How can I increment  a specific year using datetime datatype in mysql? for eg. all the dates of the year 2012 needs to be changed to 2013 without affecting the month, day and time.

Comment: Apply the basic date-time functions of your database

Comment: Brad, so far i have googled the problem. Dirk, i do not know much about sql so please try to simple it down. using functions is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
UPDATE <table-name> SET <date-column> = DATE_ADD(<date-column>, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

As  Martin mentioned in comments, If you want to increment a specific year (like in your example) add a WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE <table-name> SET <date-column> = DATE_ADD(<date-column>, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE YEAR(<date-column>) = 2012;
```

Go ahead and have a glance at [MySQL's Date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more information.

Comment: you should add `WHERE YEAR(<date-column>) = 2012`

Comment: True, Martin, my example is for incrementing all the dates by one year.

Comment: Actually you should use `WHERE <date-column> BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31';` It can use an index.

Comment: And CAST the DATE values to DATETIME for 'best results', but I don't think it was an optimization question ;)